# dot replacement with replaceText apps script google document (not sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, document

I am trying to replace dots "." with other strings in a google document using Google apps script.

My code below does not seem to do anything. Do you have any idea why ? (EDIT : it now does something)

Many thanks !

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

body.replaceText(".", "mmmmm"); // EDIT replace any literal character 
body.replaceText("\.", "mmmmm"); // EDIT : replacement done !
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Also consider marking the answer correct, or writing the answer your self and marking it correct. The current answer is helpful as it has an example. While your comments in your question were helpful, in the future consider adding some example text to help the person answering give you a great solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to double the backslashes `"\\."`.

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  console.log( body.getText() );
  body.replaceText("\\.", "xyz");
  console.log( body.getText() );
}
```

If the input is this:

```
Some text. More. done
```

Then the output will be this:

```
Some textxyz Morexyz done
```

---

**Additional notes**

When you provide your regex inside a string `"..."`, then this needs to account for the fact that string literals can contain escape characters, where the `\` has a specific meaning (the start of an escape sequence).

For example, in `"foo\tbar"` the `\t` is a tab character.

To counteract this special meaning of `\` in a string literal, you must first escape the `\`, so that it can then be used by the regular expression correctly - as a *regular expression escape character* and not as a *string literal escape character*.